# How to remove a row to a new sheet when checkbox is marked true

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a template of payment receipt in a tab for my organisation in which I am importing data from 2nd tab by using drop down & output generated is by using a filter function so the data gets populated automatically. In the template tab I have made a checkbox column & the invoice amounts totals up if the data entered in checkbox column is TRUE.

The issue in which i am stuck & need communities help in resolving it is that when I tick a checkbox that particular invoice (row) is considered as paid & when I re-select customers name from drop down the previous checked box row should not appear in the template & the original data sheet the balance pending invoices of particular selected customer should appear & also when a checkbox is ticked there should be a new column created in DATA tab or a new sheet to be created where I can summarize the data of payments received day wise of all the customers with payment received date.

I tried using a script but was unsuccessful. The script i used is in the sheet.

Please find below editable link to the sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12SPl0ZDAuJo_IonsyE2HT23WxI7wq583Y4ylh6sC6d8/edit?usp=sharing

Please suggest a solution to the problem. Any help would be proved useful for the organization.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The linked spreadsheet was deleted

Answer (score -1):

Your script is not working because the `If` conditions are never met:

- The Checkbox is a boolean, which means it will return `true` or `false`, not a `"true"` string value.
- It's also located in the 6th column, not the 3rd.

Knowing this, change your `if` to:

`if (s.getName() == "Template" && r.getColumn() == 6 && r.getValue() == true) {`

Also, the Data Validation from the column B6 will write the row again after it's deleted, so it's not necessary to delete the row as changing the value in B6 is enough:

```
 s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
 ss.getRange("B6").setValue("Broker"); //set the value to Broker or to any other value that won't write the row again
 //s.deleteRow(row);
```

I hope this helps!